# Work flow not running automatically

Tags: designer-workflow, workflow-activity

Here's the situation. I have a list & created a worke flow on it. The list has a Project Start Date & Due Dates. I need the work flow to run on or before the Project Start Date & then create a task off that list into another one. I have the generate a task part of the work flow working but I can't seem to get the work flow to kickoff on the Project Start Date that it needs to. I'm having to manually go in and run it. Any help appreciated! I have it setup to Wait for the Projet Start Date to equal Today but the work flow doesn't seem to recognize the days. I have the new sharemail point 2013 &2010. I couldn't upload a pic so here's the first stage of the workflow:

> Set variable:projectstartdate to current item:project start date (this
> is the column from my list)
>
> Then log this is the Project Start Date
>
> Variable to the workflow history list
>
> Then log this is the Recurring
> List Column: [%Current Item:Project Start Date%] to the workflow
> history list
>
> Then wait for Project Start Date to equal Today (this is
> the thing that isn't working correctly)
>
> Then set variable: DueDate to Current Item:Due Date (again,column from my list)
>
> Then set variable:occurrence to Current Itme:Occurrence
>
> Then set variable:ProjectStartDate to Current Item:Project Start Date (could
> this be the issue, the duplication of these two?)

Answer (score 0):

Functions like "Today" in SharePoint don't automatically calculate--they calculate whenever an item is modified. I.e., if a calculated field is using `TODAY()`, the moment a new record is created, the result will be always be that day until the next time that row is modified.

As for a solution, you're close to the workaround already. You'll need to change modify the record in some way every day, which will update the value of `TODAY()`. You can use a `Loop with Condition while TODAY() does not equal Project Start Date, where Project Start Date = Project Start Date until TODAY() does equal Project Start Date`. The point of constantly overwriting Project Start Date (any other field would work) is to force the row to be modified--once it does, `TODAY()` recalculates, and your "automatic" trigger would then execute the rest of your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve using 1 action you don`t have to assign to any workflow variable also.

1. Add action "Pause until date"
2. Set the pause date to current item "Project Start Date".

[image]